# C2 Zertifikat, Materialen für die Vorbereitung

Tags: learning, resource

Ich suche nach Materialen für die Vorbereitung aufs C2 Zertifikat. Ich habe schon das C1 Zertifikat bestanden und möchte noch weitermachen. Also, wenn jemand mir ein Buch, Webseite oder einfach Vorschläge vorschlagen könnte, wäre ich dieser Person sehr dankbar.

Comment: Ich habe keine Ahnung, wie anspruchsvoll das deutsche C2-Zertifikat ist, aber ich habe vor langer Zeit das Cambridge Certificate of Proficiency (also C2 für Englisch) abgelegt. Ich denke, dass man auf dem Niveau die Grammatik weitestgehend beherrscht und es ansonsten vor allem um Ausdrucksfähigkeit in vielen verschiedenen Situationen und Verständnis schwieriger Texte oder undeutlich gesprochener Dialoge/Sprache geht, und das lernt man m. E. nicht aus Lehrmaterialien, sondern aus normalen Büchern, Filmen, anderen Fernsehsendungen, und Unterhaltungen mit Muttersprachlern.

Comment: »vorwärts gehen« im übertragenen Sinne (vermutlich eine direkte Übersetzung des englischen “move forward”) gibt es im Deutschen nicht, und »jmdm. etwas teilen« (vom englischen “share sth. with sb.”?) ebensowenig. Aber die passenden Ausdrücke (z. B. »sich weiterentwickeln«, »jmdm. etwas vorschlagen«/»jmdm. Vorschläge machen«) lernst Du schnell, wenn Du Dich intensiv mit deutschsprachigen Medien aller Art auseinandersetzt.

Comment: Laut Duden gilt »vorwärts gehen« als Synomyn von »besser werden«. Deshalb habe ich gedacht, dass der Ausdruck richtig war. Vielleicht passt nicht zu diesem Kontext. Na ja, auf jedem Fall danke ich Dir für Deine Antwort. https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/vorwaertsgehen

Comment: Man kann "vorwärtsgehen" in diesem Sinn nur mit Prozessen, Projekten und dergleichen verwenden, aber nicht mit einer Person.

Comment: Was der Duden zu "vorwärtsgehen" verschweigt, ist, daß "vorwärtsgehen" im Sinne von "besser werden" nur in der Form "ES geht vorwärts|voran" gebraucht wird. Das ist eine Redewendung und nur in dieser Form zu verwenden. Es ist zB. korrekt, auf die Frage "was machen Deine Kinder?" mit "ES geht voran" zu antworten, wenn man meint, daß ein Fortschritt (zB in der Schule) erkennbar sei.

Answer (score 3):

Die C2 Prüfung ist **sehr** anspruchsvoll und es lohnt sich!

Zur Vorbereitung gibt es vom Goethe-Institut einen C2-Modellsatz und weiter unten auf der Seite gibt es einen Übungssatz: https://www.goethe.de/de/spr/kup/prf/prf/gc2/ueb.html

Ich empfehle es, beide Sätze durchzuarbeiten und zwar mit den Zeitrichtlinien, die für die tatsächliche Prüfung festgelegt werden.

Es ist auch sinnvoll, Essen und Getränke mitzubringen, weil wenn man mit der Prüfung angefangen hat, darf man das Büro nicht verlassen.

Viel Glück und viel Erfolg!