# Verwendung von "Zertifikat" als Synonym für "Prüfung"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

Diese Frage ist motivert durch [C2 Zertifikat, Materialen für die Vorbereitung](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/66058/34192) . Der Verfasser schreibt

> Ich habe schon das C1 Zertifikat bestanden.

Auf den ersten Blick kam mir das schief formuliert vor: Ein Zertifikat sollte eigentlich eine Bescheinigung oder Urkunde sein (die in diesem konkreten Fall nach Bestehen einer Sprachprüfung ausgestellt wird). Allerdings schreibt das [Goethe-Institut](https://www.goethe.de/de/m/spr/kup/prf/prf/gc1.html)

> Das Goethe-Zertifikat C1 ist eine Deutschprüfung für Erwachsene.

Hier wird also das C1 Zertifikat mit einer Prüfung gleichgesetzt; insofern kann man das C1 Zertifikat **bestehen**. Das Goethe-Institut sagt [andererseits](https://www.goethe.de/ins/de/de/m/prf/wan.html#i6351304) auch

> Das Goethe-Zertifikat in der Hand halten
> Ein Zertifikat des Goethe-Instituts ist ein international anerkannter Nachweis über Ihre Deutschkenntnisse. Es dient auch als Nachweis über Sprachfertigkeiten, die zum Beispiel im Beruf gebraucht werden. Daher ist es für unsere erfolgreichen Prüfungsteilnehmer *innen wichtig zu wissen, wann sie mit ihrem Goethe-Zertifikat rechnen können.

Diese Aussage bestätigt meine Interpretation des Begriffs "Zertifikat". Meine Frage:

*Kann das Wort "Zertifikat" tatsächlich als Synonym für "Prüfung" verwendet werden?*

Comment: Es mag sein, dass das Goethe-Institut seine Prüfung *Zertifikat* nennt, es sieht mir aber  nach einer irreführenden Bezeichnung aus. Normalerweise erhält man ein Zertifikat, nachdem man eine Prüfung bestanden hat.

Comment: @guidot Genau das denke ich auch.

Comment: *Das Abitur* ist genauso eine Prüfung - Trotzdem "haben" Menschen Abi - also ein Zertifikat für einen Bildungsabschluß.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ein Zertifikat ist einfach nur eine Bestätigungsurkunde, in diesem Fall (und auch sonst oft) über das Bestehen einer Prüfung. Die Endung -at steht für das lateinische Partizip Perfekt, hier zu *certificare* (= jemandem etwas versichern).

Alles andere, was an etwas lockerem Sprachgebrauch drumherum entstanden ist, erwächst aus meiner Sicht einfach aus der engen 1:1-Zuordnung zwischen Zertifikat und Prüfung. Die Prüfung wird vom Goethe-Institut ausschließlich in Hinblick auf das Zertifikat zusammengestellt, man unterzieht sich der Prüfung ausschließlich, um das Zertifikat zu erlangen, das Zertifikat bestätigt auschließlich die eine erfolgreich bestandene Prüfung.

Da liegt es nahe, dass die Begrifflichkeiten des Zertifikats und der Prüfung im Lauf der Zeit verwischen, ähnlich wie Studium und Abschluss in "Ich mache an der Uni im Moment meinen Master.".

Der Satz ...

> Das Goethe-Zertifikat C1 ist eine Deutschprüfung für Erwachsene.

... müsste also vielleicht strenggenommen lauten:

> Das Goethe-Zertifikat C1 ist eine Bestätigung über das Bestehen der *Prüfung für das Zertifikat C1*, einer Deutschprüfung für Erwachsene.

So sehr ich für exakte Sprache bin -- man muss einfach zugeben, dass diese exaktere Formulierung viele Worte, aber keinerlei nützliche Information hinzufügt. Wenn die Prüfung keinen anderen Zweck hat als die Erlangung des Zertifikats, ist das aus meiner Sicht eine sinnvolle und verständliche Verkürzung.

Comment: Also Deiner Meinung nach sprachliche Schlamperei (wie in meinem Kommentar zu c.p.'s Antwort erwähnt), allerdings akzeptable bzw. sogar kreative Schlamperei.

Demnach wäre tatsächlich je nach Kontext "Zertifikat" als Synonym für "Prüfung" verwendbar.

Comment: Ja, aber, wie gesagt, letzteres ist wirklich nur meine Meinung. Dass die eigentliche Bedeutung von Zertifikat Bescheinigung ist, ist aber, denke ich, ziemlich unstrittig.

Comment: Vielleicht ist das ähnlich gelagert wie "Das Auto hat noch TÜV bis Oktober". Jeder weiß, was gemeint ist, aber wörtlich darf der Satz nicht genommen werden. Schade nur, dass ausgerechnet das Goethe-Institut so locker mit der Sprache umgeht. Man hätte z.B. "Das Goethe-Zertifikat C1 wird durch eine Deutschprüfung für Erwachsene erworben" sagen können.

Comment: Ein möglicher Aspekt wäre noch, dass das Goethe-Institut es für Sprachlerner einfach ausdrücken will.

Comment: "eine Bestätigung über das Bestehen", ... aha, also eine *Besteh-tigung*?

Answer (score 7):

*Goethe-Zertifikat C1* ist der Eigenname einer Prüfung des Goethe-Instituts. Daher kann man mit dem genauen *Zertifikat* alles machen, was man mit einer Prüfung tut.

(Übrigens könnte man auch ein Auto „Zertifikat“ nennen, wenn man blöd ist, oder eine Zeitung *Bild*. Und somit könnte man „einen *Zertifikat* fahren“ und „die *Bild* lesen“ schreiben dürfen.)

Das zweite Beispiel *Das Goethe-Zertifikat in der Hand halten* könnte bedeuten, dass man schon das tatsächliche Zertifikat (also ein Papier) in der Hand, nachdem man die (fast gleichnamige) Prüfung bestanden hat.

Comment: Die Interpretation "Eigenname einer Prüfung" klingt zunächst plausibel, aber wie erklärt sich dann der Satz "Das Goethe-Zertifikat in der Hand halten"? Kann natürlich sprachliche Schlamperei sein - und das ausgerechnet vom Goethe-Institut ...

Comment: @PaulFrost Ok, die Frage ist interessant. Kann es sein, dass bei  "Das Goethe-Zertifikat in der Hand halten" wieder dem Wort Zertifikat die übliche Bedeutung gegeben wird (nur das Zertifikat ausgerechnet vom GI.). Das kommt mir wie das Emmentaler Paradox vor. Sprich: „Je mehr Käse, desto mehr Löcher. Je mehr Löcher, desto weniger Käse. Also: Je mehr Käse, desto weniger Käse“ (Lösung: erster Käse bedeutet nicht dasselbe als der zweite Käse)

Comment: @c.p. Das ist doch Käse.